# How to change, inside a class, the value of an attribute in runtime?

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following structure, where there is an abstract class with a baseDirectory attribute by default.

```
public abstract class PerformanceTest {
/**
* Base directory.
*/
private String baseDirectory = "C:/msg-inbox/";
```

...

On the other hand there is a class that extends from the abstract class.

```
public class MessagePerformanceTest extends PerformanceTest {
/**
* Constructor.
*/
public MessagePerformanceTest() {
}
```

...

Finally I have a main class like this:

```
public class MessagesMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Field field = PerformanceTest.class.getDeclaredField("baseDirectory");
          field.setAccessible(true);
          field.set(null,args[0]);

    MessagePerformanceTest messagePerformanceTest = new MessagePerformanceTest();
    messagePerformanceTest.createMessages();
```

...

The problem that i am facing is that i dont know the best way to pass de baseDirectory attribute as an argument because I need to change this value in runtime. I´m trying to use reflection but its not working by the moment. Have anyone idea about a possible workaround?

To sum up I need to change de default value C:/msg-inbox/ to another thing similar to \folder1\test

Regards

Comment: why not provide a constructor `PerformanceTest(String)`?

Comment: Its impossible in this situation

Comment: well, sounds like simple setter would work just fine) why do you need reflection at all for such simple operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`baseDirectory` is an instance field, meaning it belongs to an instance of `PerformanceTest`. So to change its value you need an instance of  `PerformanceTest`.

But `PerformanceTest` is abstract class so you cant have its instance. Lucky you have its base class `MessagePerformanceTest` to create instance of type `PerformanceTest`.
You need something like this:
note: I have created get() method to check the changed value.

```
public abstract class PerformanceTest {
/**
* Base directory.
*/
private String baseDirectory = "C:/msg-inbox/";

    public String get(){
        return baseDirectory;
    }
}
```

---

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new MessagePerformanceTest().get() );
          Field field = PerformanceTest.class.getDeclaredField("baseDirectory");
          field.setAccessible(true);
          MessagePerformanceTest  mpt = new MessagePerformanceTest ();
          field.set( mpt," \folder1\test");
          System.out.println(mpt.get() );
    }

}
```

mpt is an instance of MessagePerformanceTest and hence instance of type PerformanceTest